# what is the jacobian of the rotation function applied to angles?

Tags: rotations, jacobian

I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to compute the Jacobian of a function but having some hard time doing so.
I'll first give a intuitive description of the function and then I'll try to make it more formal.

The Jacobian I come up with has some fundamental problems (biggest example: when there is no rotation i.e $R=I$ I get that the partial derivative does not exist). It seem to me this problem should have an easier solution other than brute force using sympy...

verbal description (i.e hand waving):

The function gets 3 Euler angles (yaw, pitch and roll) and uses some rotation matrix $R$ to change the CS in which these angles are given. (Compute rotation matrix $\hat{R}$ from the angles and extract the Euler angles from $R\cdot \hat{R} \cdot R^T$)

Attempt to be more formal:

Let $$\psi=\{R \ |\ R\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}, R\cdot R^T=I \\\wedge \\\text{det}(R)=1\}$$

$$f: \mathbb{R}^3\times\psi \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$
$$g: \mathbb{R}^3\ \rightarrow \psi$$
$$h:  \psi\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$
$$f(v, R)=h(R\cdot g(v) \cdot R^T) $$

to be clear - I'm looking for $J_R(f_R)$ where $f_R(v)=f(v, R)$

I omitted the formal definition of $g$ and $h$. they are basically the functions that compose (g) and decompose (h) rotation matrices from Euler angles.

h is something along this:

$$h(R)^{(1)}=atan2(R_{2, 3}, \sqrt{R_{1, 3}^2 + R_{3, 3}^2})$$
$$h(R)^{(2)}=atan2(R_{1, 3}, R_{3, 3})$$
$$h(R)^{(3)}=atan2(-R_{2, 1}, R_{2, 2})$$

g is something like this:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\cos(y) &0& \sin(y)\\ 0& 1& 0\\ -\sin(y)&0&  \cos(y)\\\end{matrix} \right]
\times 
\left[\begin{matrix}1 &0& 0\\ 0& \cos(p)& \sin(p)\\ 0& -\sin(p)& \cos(p)\\\end{matrix} \right]
\times 
\left[\begin{matrix}\cos(r) &\sin(r)& 0\\ -\sin(r)& \cos(r)& 0\\ 0& 0& 1\\\end{matrix}\,\right] $$

Hope it's clear and that I made no typing mistakes..

Thanks.

Comment: even an instructed answer of reaching something that helps me will be very helpful. the solution I achieved so far is not differentiable in $I$ which is very unsatisfying

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to solve the same problem for yaw-pitch-roll rotations but gave up since it's too complicated.
Instead, I assumed that the rotation is small, and used the transformation matrix which converts the rotation rates in the global frame to the inertial frame

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta \phi \\
\delta \theta \\
\delta \psi
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-sin(\theta_1)\\
0&cos(\phi_1)&sin(\phi_1)cos(\theta_1)\\
0&-sin(\phi_1)&cos(\phi_1)cos(\theta_1)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_2-\phi_1\\
\theta_2-\theta_1\\
\psi_2-\psi_1\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and then apply jacobian to that matrix.
It seems like your rotation sequence is pitch-roll-yaw.
You may find the appropriate transformation matrix by following:
https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/robotics-n-intelligent-systems/rsl-dam/documents/RobotDynamics2016/RD2016script.pdf

Hope it helps.